# What is the compatible drone frame for

Tags: drone-frame, toy-grade-drone

I have four 3.7v coreless motors. The motors have a diameter of 7mm and length of 17 mm, with 45 mm propellers.
What is the compatible drone frame kit for this?

Comment: I'd image any specific size of motor would fit many different drones. Are there any other requirements for your drone that could help narrow down your question?

Comment: I have this motor and propeller already. So any drone frame kit where this motor can be easily mounted. Also of course it probably has to be a tiny frame because of the propeller size